# Can't HTML Scrape Site Because Of SSL Error

Tags: php, curl, openssl, web-scraping

I am working on a scraping script. It works on most websites but I cannot access a specific SSL site.

Here is my code:

```
if (!extension_loaded('openssl')){
    // not occurring
}

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.chase.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if($result === false)
{
    $err = curl_error($ch);
    //$err = SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 10054
}
```

`$result` is always `FALSE`, and it shows this error message:

```
SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 10054
```

But it works on other websites that have SSL. I also checked `phpinfo()`, cURL and OpenSSL are active. I am using WAMP, any ideas?

Comment: Why are you trying to scrape a banking website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a Useragent. I tested with and without one and it fixes the issue. It appears Chase is wanting a UA to be provided in the request.

So add this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 9.0; WIndows NT 9.0; en-US)');
```

Comment: wow you are right :/
Thanks!
PS: I was actually setting a useragent (I just removed some lines I thought useless) but I think I wasn't setting it correctly, yours works!

Comment: @DanielStenberg yeah I got the same error. I had to add `echo $err;` of course.

Comment: ok, cool. Just seemed unusual to get an SSL error due to lack of user-agent. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

I solved issue by just using following PHP librery.

https://github.com/rmccue/Requests

[use this library code on your Linux based server, may be it will not work on xampp or wamp ]